How to update the page data when switch rowsperpage in PaginatedDataTable?
for example, when I switch to rowperpage=10 on the second page (page=2) with rowperpage=5, the index is rendered as 6-15of totalnum in the bottom right corner of the table, but i think it's wrong because of I think this second page has to start with 10.
Example 2: when page=2, rowperpage=5, I switch to rowperpage=15, the index in the lower right corner of the table is 11-25 of totalnum.But I think the correct display should be 16-30.
Is my code not refreshing somewhere?
I have used the unique key to PaginatedDataTable instance,but in this way the page can't be fliped, every time the page is fliped, the index is 1-rowsperpage of totalNums.
I have updated flutter to Flutter 3.22.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b0850be (5 days ago) • 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
Engine • revision 235db911ba
Tools • Dart 3.4.4 • DevTools 2.34.3，but the questions I posed above remain.
Here is what I have provided only minimal but complete reproducible code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DomainList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return DomainListState();
  }
}

class DomainListState extends State {
  final GlobalKey<State> _key = GlobalKey();
  int rowsPerPage = 10;
  int currentPage = 1;
  late MyDataTableSource myDS =
      MyDataTableSource(state: this, context: context);

  bool ascending = false;
  int sortColumnIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myDS.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void changeRowsPerPage(int value) {
    setState(() {
      rowsPerPage = value;
      myDS.fetchdomainPage(currentPage, rowsPerPage);
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

  void changePage(int pageIndex) {
    setState(() {
      currentPage = pageIndex ~/ rowsPerPage + 1;
      myDS.fetchdomainPage(currentPage, rowsPerPage);
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) => PaginatedDataTable(
              columnSpacing: 1,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (int? value) {
                if (value != null) {
                  changeRowsPerPage(value);
                }
              },
              initialFirstRowIndex: 0,
              rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage,
              availableRowsPerPage: const <int>[5, 10, 15, 20],
              onPageChanged: (pageIndex) {
                changePage(pageIndex);
              },
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('域名'),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text('属性'),
                ),
              ],
              source: myDS,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDataTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  MyDataTableSource({required this.state, required this.context}) {
    dataList = [];
    rowsPerPage = state.rowsPerPage;
    page = state.currentPage;
    fetchdomainPage(page, rowsPerPage);
  }

  late DomainListState state;
  late BuildContext context;
  final bool _isDisposed = false;
  List<DomainModel> dataList = [];
  int selectedCount = 0;
  late int page;
  late int rowsPerPage;
  late int totalItems = 50;

  Future<void> fetchdomainPage(int? page, int? rowsPerPage) async {
    //Mock
    //replace the original backend request with a fixed return value
    page = state.currentPage;
    rowsPerPage = state.rowsPerPage;
    dataList.clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= rowsPerPage; i++) {
      dataList.add(DomainModel(name: 'Domain $i', property: 0));
    }
    if (!_isDisposed) {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    page = state.currentPage;
    print('Page: ' '$page' ', Rows per page: ${state.rowsPerPage}');
    var dataIndex = index - (page - 1) * state.rowsPerPage;
    // var dataIndex = index % state.rowsPerPage;

    print('index' '$index');
    print('dataIndex' '$dataIndex');

    if (dataIndex >= dataList.length || dataIndex < 0) {
      return null;
    }

    DomainModel domainModel = dataList[dataIndex];
    return DataRow.byIndex(index: index, cells: <DataCell>[
      DataCell(Text(domainModel.name ?? '--')),
      DataCell(Text(domainModel.property == 0 ? '非根域' : '根域')),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => totalItems;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => selectedCount;
}

class DomainModel {
  int? id;
  int? property;
  String? name;

  DomainModel({
    this.id,
    this.property,
    this.name,
  });
}

